# Intersections of measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $A_1,A_2,...\in \mathcal{A}$. 
Assume that  $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(A_j)<\infty.$ 
I have already proved following statements:

(1) $n \cdot \mu (\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j)\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(A_j) $

(2) $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu (\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j)=0$

(3) $ \mu (\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j)=0$

I need to prove that if we set

$ E=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty (\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty  A_k)$

then i follows that $ \mu(E)=0$.

Can anyone help med with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
B_j=\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty  A_k.
$$ 
Then $B_j$ is measurable and
$$
m(B_j)\le \sum_{k\ge j}m(A_k).
$$
But
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(A_k)<\infty,
$$
implies that
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty}\sum_{k\ge j}^\infty m(A_k)=0.
$$
Finally
$$ 
E=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty (\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty  A_k)=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty B_j,
$$
and hence
$$
m(E)\le m(B_j), \quad\text{for all $j$},
$$
and as $m(B_j)\to 0$, then $m(E)=0$.